# Question about meaning of "proof of status" in this context

Tags: word-meaning, legalese

The visit won't be very complicated, but to apply for your SIN (Social Insurance number) you'll need to bring your: confirmation of permanent or other proof of **status** in Canada like a work or study permit, and your passport.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what got you confused here. I think the body itself is self-explanatory. *Proof of Status* is a person's legal standing/status with which he/she resides in a country. For students, it's study permit/visa. For working professionals, it's work permit/visa. Similarly there can be [temporary resident visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) for tourists and visitors, and so on.

Here's the definition of Proof of Status from the [US Embassy in Laos](http://laos.usembassy.gov/glossary.html)

> ***Proof of Status*** - This term refers to the legal status of the petitioner in the United States. A petitioner must be a U.S. citizen,
>   or a lawful permanent resident currently living in the U.S., if he or
>   she wants to bring another immigrant to the U.S. Therefore, a
>   petitioner must present a U.S. passport or a valid green
>   card--residency must not have expired (which may occur if a petitioner
>   has been out of the U.S. for over 6 months). Appropriate evidence is
>   necessary.